# Creating a Binary Tree from prefix with OOP and recursion in python

Tags: python, oop, recursion, binary-tree

I'm pretty new to programming and i've been trying to create a binary tree from prefix expression. I have tried for over 20 hours, on my own, with youtube videos and google but still can't seem to get it right.

What i've done so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.parent=None
        self.lst=lst
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.root=None
        
    def create_tree(self,lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[i].isdigit():
                node=Node(lst)
            else:
                self.parent=lst[i]
                self.left=self.create_tree(lst[i+1])
                self.right=self.create_tree(lst[i+2])
                lst.remove(self.parent)
                lst.remove(self.left)
                lst.remove(self.right)
                node=Node(lst)
                return lst
lst=["+","2","3"]
node=Node(lst)
node.create_tree(lst)
```

Can someone explain to me what i'm missing or doing wrong to get this to work? It needs to be in a class and I want to use recursion to solve this problem, and not a stack.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For about half of the code you presented I have no idea what is intending to do. What was your intention with `Node(lst)`, with `lst.remove(self.parent)`, with `self.parent=lst[i]`, ...etc. It makes little sense to me. Can you add comments to your code to explain your intention?

Comment: I'm just as confused as you are sir. For lst.remove it was because my teacher told me that after I assign each character from the string to a node, that I then need to remove that character from that list. Self.parent is the parent for the 2 nodes that come after it, so [i] is the parent, [i+1] is the first child and [i+2] is the second child. But I probably have got this all wrong, maybe i'll just start over. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But `lst` does not contain nodes, so why would you do `self.parent=lst[i]`? Shouldn't `self.parent` reference a `Node` instance? And if you step back, were you really asked to have nodes with a `parent` attribute? This should not be necessary.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. And no I was not told to use parent as an attribute, I'll remove it and keep trying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to comment on this code, and I fear not much can survive. This is an incomplete list of issues:

- A `Node` instance should not have a `root` member. That would require you to copy the root reference to **all** nodes in the tree. That is making things hard to maintain, and is just not how it is done. Instead define a second class that represents a tree (not just a node). That class will have the `root` attribute.
- A `Node` should certainly not get a reference to `lst`. That list just contains the pre-order, and has no role to play in a node at all.
- Although for some uses it is nice to have a `parent` reference in a `Node` instance, many times this is not necessary: as you start navigating a tree from the root, you always *know* where you came from, so when you arrive at a node, you already know what its parent is (you just came from there). So *storing* it is often just creating work instead of solving anything useful.
- When you go for recursion, you should not have a `for` loop over the whole list. Either you iterate with a loop over the list and have no recursion, or you have recursion -- passing it the rest of the list -- and have no loop over the same list.
- `node=Node(lst)` is wrong: you don't want to create node for the *whole* list. You'll want a node for just one of its values, i.e. for `lst[i]`.
- `self.parent=lst[i]` is wrong: you don't want to reference a list entry, but a node instance. But as I pointed out above, you don't need this `parent` really, so drop this.
- The calls to `remove` are wrong for several reasons:

  - It mostly leads to problems when you remove from a list that you are also iterating.
  - As you already leave out `lst[0]` when making the recursive call, there is no need to remove anything.
- `return lst` is wrong, because the caller expects a node, not a list. Moreover, there is no `return` happening in the `if` block, so then you return `None` which is also wrong.

This is not a complete list of issues, but it shows that you need to rewrite much of that code.

Here I will propose the use of an iterator over the input list: with the `next` method you can easily get the next value of a list, and don't need to fiddle with indexes and slices:

```
class Node:
    # Constructor accepts two optional arguments so to set left and right subtrees
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        it = iter(lst) # Create an iterator over the list
        
        def create_tree():  # Helper function
            value = next(it, None)
            if value is None:  # No more value
                return None
            if value.isdigit():  # We need a leaf node
                return Node(value)
            # Use recursion to build the left and right subtree and
            #     create a Node instance with them as children
            return Node(value, create_tree(), create_tree())

        self.root = create_tree()
```

Your main code can then be:

```
lst = ["+","2","3"]
tree = Tree(lst)
```

NB: You'll probably want to add a function to display the tree.

Comment: Note: If having a reference to the parent `Node` is useful (it often is), it would still be safer to store it as a `weakref.ref` or `weakref.proxy`. Stored as a strong reference, on CPython (where lifetime is *usually* deterministic) your trees will be cleaned non-deterministically (whenever the cyclic garbage collector gets around to being invoked); stored as a weak reference, the tree won't have cyclic references, and can be cleaned immediately when the last reference to the tree is dropped (if no other cycles are involved).

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I learned a lot about binary trees and recursion from your answer. Can I ask why the create_tree method is inside of the init method?

Comment: Alternatively it could have been a static method taking the iterator as argument. As an instance method it would not use the instance, so that would not be the right choice. It's just a choice where to put it.

Comment: hey trincot, I made a new post about adding parents to this code, is it possible for you to take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74786609/adding-parent-pointer-to-each-node-when-creating-binary-expression-tree